# Initializing dynamic array of unions in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, unions

I've tried to make an array of union and my code looks like that:

```
printf("Size of array:");
scanf_s(" %d", &n);

f* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

I have my union declared like that:

```
        union element
    {
        int digit;
        char letter;
        float number;
    } f;
```

And I don't really know how to declare array of unions in C. 
I tried something like this:

```
f* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

and like this:

```
float* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

and this:

```
element* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(f));
```

Any of them works!

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a union type do

```
union element
{
    int digit;
    char letter;
    float number;
};
```

To dynamical allocated an array with `n` elements of type `union element` do:

```
union element * pu = malloc(n * sizeof (union element));
```

or even better

```
union element * pu = malloc(n * sizeof *pu);
```

---

The code you show here

```
union element
{
    int digit;
    char letter;
    float number;
} f;
```

does two things:

1. Define a type `union element`
2. Define the variable `f` to be of type `union element`

---

*Note*

If this

```
 element* arr = malloc(n * ...
```

compiles, then you are not using a C compiler, but a C++ compiler.

A C compiler required

```
 union element* arr = malloc(n * ...
```

---

A final comment on your wording: "*Initiallizing ... array ...*":

The code dynamical *creates* n elements of a union. Those element do *not* get "initialized".

To have them being initialised during allocation of `calloc()` instrad of `malloc()`;

```
... = calloc(n, sizeof ...); /* Note the different number of parameters. */
```

Comment: When I do it, as you told, I got an error - 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'element *' note: Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: @im_a_cat: This means you do *not* use a C compiler, but a C++ compiler.

Comment: I changed my compiler and it works, thank you so much!